# How to show that the following function is Schwarz

Tags: fourier-analysis

We know $f(x)$ is in Schwartz  space if for given  $m,k $ non-negative integers  the supremum of $ \left|x^{m  }  f^{(k)}(x) \right| $ over  the real numbers is finite.
Let $a $ be positive real and $f(t) = (|\Gamma  (a+ i t )| )^2 $ is in Schwarz  space.

Comment: Hint: Use the integral representation of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: then how to differentiate general times

Comment: i am unable  to  proceed can u hint little more please...

Comment: The idea is to differentiate under the integral sign. You will be getting some logarithmic factors each time you differentiate.

Comment: wil i have double integral

Comment: because  mod power two is there so  we have gamma into gamma bar

Comment: The Fourier transform sends $S(\mathbb{R}) \to S(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{s}$ and $\Gamma(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^{-x}} e^{-sx}dx$ for $Re(s) > 0$. Overall for $-\sigma \not \in \mathbb{N}, g(t) = \Gamma(\sigma+it)$ is Schwartz and hence $|g(t)|^2$ too